# Calling custom delegate from AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this delegate in AppDelegate.swift that fires once another app opens my app with a url scheme.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return true
 }
```

It fires just fine when another app opens my app with the url scheme, but when this function fires, I want to notify a certain ViewController. I thought I could do this with a custom made delegate, and let the AppDelegate notify who ever implements my delegate that someone has opened the app.

**MyDelegate.swift**

```
protocol MyDelegate {
    func opened(hasBeenOpened: Bool!)
}
```

Then my ViewController implements this Delegate

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

/* Obviously this class has more code and other functions, 
but for the illustration of the problem, I removed all the other unrelated things.*/

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate {
    func opened(hasBeenOpened: Bool!) {
        print(hasBeenOpened)
    }
}
```

So far so good, but let's return to the openURL() function in AppDelegate.swift and try to call the MyDelegate.opened(). This is where I am completely lost.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        print("openURL delegate running")

        if var delegate = MyDelegate?() {
            delegate.opened(true)
        }

        return true
    }
```

The console prints "openUrl delegate running", so it's running, but my delegate variable becomes `nil`. Is there some initialization I'm missing?

I can't seem to figure out how I call my own custom Delegate from the AppDelegate. Is there another way to notify ViewControllers that this has happened? Or is this a bad idea overall, is there another way that's considered better?

Thank you all in advance, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure delegates are the appropriate way to achieve this. The problem is that you would need to have a delegate variable in your AppDelegate and then set it in your LoginViewController. But in your openURL method you might not have an instantiated LoginViewController yet. Do you just want to show LoginViewController ?

Comment: I basically want to call a function on LoginViewController the openURL method. But it seems weird to call a function on a ViewController from AppDelegate. I thought I'd rather register an delegate so who ever implements the the delegate can listen for the event.

Comment: Not only the delegate, your VC object will also be `nil`, can you please tell what do you want to do, I mean notify the VC for what ?

Comment: @VinayJain I am using a third party bank app, to authenticate my user, and when the authentication is complete, the bank app with open my app again with a url scheme. When this happenes, the openURL in AppDelegate is running. I just want to notify my LoginViewController that the user has tried to authenticate with the bank app, so I can collect the login from the bank web service and see if it was a success or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to initialise a protocol (`var delegate = MyDelegate?()`) which is not possible.

The way you use delegates is by registering conformance on a class, which you are doing in `LoginViewController`, and calling a method defined in the protocol directly on an instance of that class.

For example:

```
var loginViewController = // get an instance of LoginViewController
loginViewController.opened(true)
```

In this case you don't have access to an instance, nor would it be considered good practice to keep a reference to a view controller in the App Delegate. So I think the paradigm you are looking for is notifications. Have a look at the documentation for [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) or the [NSHipster article on notifications](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/).

Comment: Is it considered a bad practice to call a function on LoginViewController from the AppDelegate, due to encapsulation of the classes. I don't necessarily want my AppDelegate to know about my LoginViewController. Maybe notifications is a good solution then.

Comment: @StefanKonno I agree, nsnotification might be a great solution, but it depends what exactly you want to do. If no LoginViewController is instantiated, your method won't be called, is that a problem ?

Comment: The LoginViewController is the entrypoint of my app, so it should be instantiated always when my openURL in AppDelegate is running. I'll make sure of it otherwise.

Comment: @StefanKonno yes, with the possible exception of the app's root view controller, I would never reference UI elements from the App Delegate as it is intended for interaction with the system.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my thought. That's why I thought I would register an event, that the ViewController could listen to. I'll have a look at notifications instead of delegates then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Without going into details if this is a good or bad idea, the problem is your `delegate` property in `AppDelegate` is never initialized. In the initializer method of your `UIViewController` you need to get access to the AppDelegate and set the delegate property to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Try NSNotification，I don't think it is a good idea to hold specific view controller in AppDelegate.